# How to create a data using relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I had experience some weird behaviour, while creating data using laravel relationship. I get the user data with an `id` of `2`, but when I create a data relationship, the `user_id` returned is `1`.

Somebody knows what went wrong?

---

I test it using tinker, firstly I get the user data. And it displays the data successfully.

```
$user = User::find(2);
=> App\Models\User {#4292
     id: 2,
     username: "usefrfff@gmail.com",
     status_id: 1,
     created_at: "2021-03-21 12:14:17",
     updated_at: "2021-03-21 12:14:17",
   }
```

The second one I create log data using the relationship.

```
$user->logs()->create(['type_id' => 2]);
=> App\Models\Log {#4294
     type_id: 2,
     user_id: 1,
     id: 11,
   }
```

---

**User.php**

```
public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class);
}
```

**Log.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the same with a different user? Check if the ID of the user is displayed in your logs.

Comment: @MegaColorBoy yeah I tried different user, but it still printing `user_id: 1`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what actually can cause such a problem,

But you could try to specify the foreign key for the logs function

```
public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class,'user_id');
}
```

Hopefully that will make it work!

Comment: tried this but same problem occured. thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```php
// in user model
public function logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Log::class,'user_id','id');
}

// in log model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After invistagating the **Log.php**, I found out that it has an *Observer*, that puts a default value while creating a data.

There is nothing wrong with the relationships. I fixed it by removing the `Observer`.